# Google Analytics content experiment vs. funnel visualization

Tags: google-analytics

I am running an experiment on one of the pages in my funnel (the "Choose shipping options" page). But the numbers on the different reports do not correspond. First, I am expecting the 70 entrances in the funnel to equal the 131 experiment visits. Also, I expect the 23 conversions in the funnel to match the 21 transactions below. But they do not. How should I read this information to make good decisions?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

William - I'm not sure on the discrepancy in Goal Starts (i.e. experiment visits/entrances to the funnel), but everything else looks good. The important part is the conversion rate comparison for your two start pages; and that data *is* showing in your Content Experiment. I wouldn't worry too much about the entrances at this point; in fact, because both your A and B page are represented in the same funnel, the funnel can only show you aggregate conversion rate and aggregate funnel conversions (i.e. both A and B combined) and really only serves to confirm the conversion rate expressed in your content experiment.

I've tried running 2 funnels into 1 experiment (which would be ideal, because you could see how your A and B pages affect the entire funnel, individually), but ran into problems with my total conversions being overstated.